# Bash read stdin line by line, and preserve null bytes

Tags: bash, pipe, byte, stdin

I'm currently using `read` to read from stdin line by line, but the input I'm reading contains null bytes, and storing the input in a variable removes them. Is there any way to get the data either as hex or base64, or get `read` to pipe the input to a specified command? (Pipes preserve null bytes)

What I have is a Bash script that gets called by [`websocketd`](https://github.com/joewalnes/websocketd), and given an encoded Protobuf message. Because of how `websocketd` works, each line is a WebSocket message, which means that I have to read each line individually, preserving null bytes and all so that I can correctly decode the message using [`protoc`](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/).

Comment: Does the read have to specifically be line by line? If the other program can accept input on its stdin (e.g. a pipe) you could call that program and let it read stdin itself, null bytes and all, instead of calling read and then trying to pass the result of that into the program.

Comment: @tjm3772 thanks, I'll edit my question to add a bit of context.

Comment: Using a delimiter for a binary protocol doesn't sound good. Won't the protofuf messages contain `\n`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo That's a good point, but I have to use some kind of separator to differentiate each message. Also, this is how `websocketd` separates each message. So if this has to be done a different way, I might have to PR it

Comment: @LuisAFK Yes, `websocketd` adds a `\n` after each message, but `websocketd` is designed to work with text messages. There's been suggestions ([Raw protocol support (for binary messages)](https://github.com/joewalnes/websocketd/issues/38)) to extend it to be able to prepend each message with a length (instead of using a delimiter). Another proposal was to add a `--binary` option and to just forward everything that comes in as-is to the started process without adding length or a delimiter. I'm not sure if anything of that was ever implemented though, and if not, I don't think it'll work.

Comment: @TedLyngmo yeah I had a look at the issue you linked earlier but they don't seem to have implemented that. Currently testing the binary flag but it doesn't seem to do much apart from allowing binary output.

Comment: @LuisAFK Binary output from the server is what you need if you are going to receive binary input on the client side. Do you have to read it in into a bash variable or can't you pass it directly to a protoc client? I haven't used it myself so I don't know if that option exists.

Comment: @TedLyngmo no need to read it into a variable, I could pipe it directly into `protoc`. And that's exactly what this question was about. Right now, I was using `while IFS='$\n' read -r line; do` but that stores it in `$line`, and Bash variables can't contain null bytes. So how would I read line by line without using variables?

Comment: @LuisAFK In binary data, there are no lines. You would have to pass the output directly to the program that is capable of decoding the binary data.  Your bash script would instead of reading from `stdin` just start that program that does the reading.

Comment: @TedLyngmo could this be done in Bash? https://github.com/joewalnes/websocketd/issues/38#issuecomment-1609984305

Comment: If they change it like you proposed, you could first read the lenght of the chunk into a variable and then use a bash command capable of reading exactly that many bytes _and_ convert it into a format that a bash variable can handle. `\0` isn't allowed as you know and the binary data _will_ contain `\0`. But are you sure they append a `\n` to each message even in `--binary` mode? That seems ... odd

Comment: @TedLyngmo yeah, even in binary they seem to be adding newlines. I just wrapped a simple `cat > log.txt` with binary mode enabled, and for each message the client sends it writes it to a new line.

Comment: Ok, and it's not that the message itself contains a text message that actually ends with a newline?

Comment: @TedLyngmo messages containing newlines are put on different lines in the log file, which means Bash would see it as different messages. This is in binary mode by the way.